# Android Ethernet Connection on x86 machine

Tags: android, virtual-machine

How do I connect an Android image running on Virtual Box to Ethernet?

I have installed it on a cloud. I can run it there but cannot connect it to the Ethernet. It's an x86 image.

Comment: Are you talking about the android emulator?

Comment: What version did of Android x86 did you install? If you installed any of the 2.x branch, the networking works just fine by default. Make sure to enable the network in bridge mode in Virtual Box settings. If you are using 4.x branch, the networking is somewhat problematic. You can type these commands in terminal to get the network setup: 
`- su
- dhcpcd eth0
- route add default gw yourgateway dev eth0
- setprop net.dns1 yourDNS`

Answer (score 8):

Just today i tried live Android 9 (Android x86) and 10 (Bliss 12.6) running on QEMU (virt-manager). Open wifi settings, switch on and tap on VirtWifi network.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I really need to use _cable_ connection and avoid wi-fi ;)

Comment: its a cable connection, not wifi. just unified settings for it

Answer (score 3):

**Press:**
ALT + F1

**Type:**

netcfg eth0 dhcp

setprop net.dns1 8.8.8.8

---

Step 5 from:
http://standroid.blogspot.de/2012/06/android-4-x86-in-virtualbox.html

Comment: Netcfg is dropped in Android x86 from v6.0, apparently.

Comment: @DavidRefoua you are right. Does anyone know how to resolve this error?